# How to query sqlite database from array in android

Tags: android

I am using the following, where `AuthorName` column value i want to find on the basis of `AuthorID`. `catid` is an array that contains `AuthorID`

```
public Cursor Authorname(String[] catid)   {
   myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT AuthorName FROM AUTHOR_NAME WHERE AuthorID = ?",catid);
}
```

but it return `IllegalArgumentException`. Can anybody help me to short out this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the logcat output?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 138 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

Comment: Which value in `catId` do you want bound to the query?

Comment: @shreya  basically I dont find any way to qwery an sqlite database from array value(catid in my qwest).Any help will pe appreciable

Comment: @trojanfoe  in catID contain authorid, on the basis of that array i want to fetch value from another column

Comment: An array has multiple values, so **which** value from the array do you want to use?  The answer will be to change `catId` to something like `catId[0]`.

Comment: I want to fetch value of every item of array from corresponding column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only one query to get all the users. Here's an example.

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT AuthorName FROM AUTHOR_NAME WHERE AuthorID IN %ids";

public Cursor Authorname(String[] catid) {

    // Build the string with all the IDs, e.g. "(1,2,3,4)"
    StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder();
    ids.append("(");
    for(int i = 0; i < catid.length; i++) {
        ids.append(String.valueOf(catid[i]);
        if (i < catid.length - 1) {
            ids.append(",");
        }
    }
    ids.append(")");

    // Use the string with the ids in the query
    String finalQuery = QUERY.replaceAll("%ids", ids.toString());

    // Execute the query
    return myDataBase.rawQuery(finalQuery);
}
```

Comment: Won't you need to quote those strings?  (if they aren't `String`s then why pass them as `String[]`?)

Comment: since I authorid is int value & I am taking this as String value...aM I WRONG THIS POINT

Comment: I got what I want...but I dont have sufficient reputation to mark this up:(

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). You have to click on the check box below the votes to accept an answer :)

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm not quoting them, check again. Quote in SQL is `'`, not `"`. And even if you quote them, IIRC SQLite will convert them if the target column is a number.

Comment: My point is that if they are strings then they need quoting, and if they aren't strings then they should be passed as `int[]`.

Comment: actully Authorid is in int form like..715,902,58...etc, but I used String[] to hold these...n now i am getting exact what I want from your above code

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, he should pass them as int[] instead, because they're actually number IDs. Also he should not start a method name with upper case in Java. But this is really not relevant to the question.

Answer (score -3):

Change your query

```
myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT AuthorName FROM AUTHOR_NAME WHERE AuthorID = ?",catid);
```

as below

```
cursor = myDataBase.query("AUTHOR_NAME",
                    new String[] {"AuthorName"}, "AuthorID IN(?)", catid, null, null, null);
```

Try the above Solution hope it works for you.

Comment: I really don't think that will work. You're only declaring one argument on the SQL sentence and pass it an array of arguments.

Comment: @user1934547 I would suggest to follow m0skit0 answer

Comment: @user1934547 See there is not such multiple value where query yet in sql so you have to do it in m0skit0 answer way.